# installing gologin on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation

I have tried to move gologin extracted file to my preferred installation folder (/opt) but am getting this error
"mv: cannot stat 'gologin': No such file or directory" kindly assist.

Comment: where is it currently and what commands are you using to move it. Were you following [these instructions](https://support.gologin.com/en/articles/8390514-installing-gologin-on-linux)

Comment: I followed the instructions and am not even receiving any error.